# Using a checkbox to show data in other cells

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way that when you put a check in a checkbox it will show number values in two separate cells? I'm creating an assessment that will have 20 questions, each question will have 2 or 3 choices (checkbox). Each choice (checkbox) will have 2 numbers that are in two separate columns. Those two columns will be totaled at the bottom of the assessment in their respective columns.

Comment: When I put =A108*6 in the H108 cell, it changes the 6 to a 0. Then I linked the checkbox in A108 to H108, check the box and it changes H108 from 0 to TRUE. Then when I unchecked the box, it changes to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps to understand the sequence of actions to solve your problem:

[image: Set numbers to checkbox value]